# Passing a var from script in classic asp?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, var

I have this script

```
<script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myvalue = (value-from-myscript.js);
document.write (myvalue);
</script>
```

"document.write" works fine inside the script but how can I get "myvalue"
and use it inside classic asp?

How can I make this work?

```
<%
pmyvalue = "myvalue"
pmyvalue2 = "myvalue2"
pmyvalue3 = "myvalue2"
mySQL="INSERT INTO mytable (value, value2, value3) VALUES ('"pmyvalue"','"pmyvalue2"','"pmyvalue3"')"
%>
```

I have "myvalue2" and "myvalue3" on this page

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this fails is because the second script, the one between `<%` and `%>`, is a server-side script that executes *on the server*.  It's executed as the page is emitted from the server.  The value you're trying to grab exists only in the browser, so therefore this fails.

Rather than doing this in a server-side script, you need to call a method on the server, or call the page a second time, passing the value you want to insert.

Comment: You can always use AJAX to call a .asp page on the server and then refresh the page with the results.